# Rangy & ContentEditable - Set the Caret

Tags: jquery, contenteditable, rangy

I'm trying out the latest version of the "rangy" jQuery plugin (1.2 beta) to set the caret in a contenteditable DIV with a specific offset.

However, it responds with a weird error in Firefox:
Security error" code: "1000

Here is the offending code:

```
var el = $("#editablediv"), index = 11;
var range = rangy.createRange();
range.setStart(el, index);
var sel = rangy.getSelection();
sel.setSingleRange(range);
```

The code fails when calling the setStart function.

Could anyone give an example of the proper usage of rangy please?

Comment: It was Security error" code: "1000, but I'm sorted. It expected a text node.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the issue, I was supposed to pass through the correct node which is the text node:

```
var el = $("#editablediv"), index = 11;
var range = rangy.createRange();
range.setStart(el[0].childNodes[0], index);
range.collapse(true);
var sel = rangy.getSelection();
sel.setSingleRange(range);
```

Comment: Yes. There were two problems with the original code: first, `setStart()` requires a DOM node rather than a jQuery object, and second, you were probably thinking in terms of character offsets which means you need the text node, as you realized.